# How can I build a view that shows the number of nodes in a taxonomy?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm looking to create something that looks a bit like:

- Term 1 (31 nodes)
- Term 2 (53 nodes)

I've done this before on Drupal 6 (it was fiddly), but I can't seem to do it again on Drupal 7. Can anyone do this?

Comment: Basically, I'd suggest altering the views output in any way (on a handler level (i.e. creating a new field handler), on the query level (hook_views_query_alter) or on the template level (views-view--field-term.tpl.php)). There, have a db query like "SELECT count(tid) FROM taxonomy_data WHERE vid=vocab_id" and output that data. It does not really matter when you do that query, since it is an extra query anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try the instructions at http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2012/01/20/drupal-7-get-number-of-nodes-of-taxonomy-term-in-views/

Answer (score 0):

I think I've done what you're looking for on a sandbox site that I have: http://www.intermodalexchange.com/, check the right hand column.  I used taxonomy menu module (http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu), and checked the "Display numbers" option.